# Concerns when applying to a Mathematics PhD with a physics degree

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, united-states

I'm a **physics graduate** from a Southern Asian country interested in starting a **PhD in mathematics in a US institution**. I have some concerns about the **lack of Analysis and Algebra** honors level courses in my profile. Following are some information about me.

1. After graduation, I'm unofficially attending some upper level mathematics courses in a university. It seems possible I won't be able to finish courses before Fall 2023 deadlines.
2. I have one year graduate level experience in differential geometry.
3. I have some research experience in mathematics.

I think the lack of a one year sequence in Analysis and Algebra might have an adverse effect in my application. One possible solution might be to get LORs from the professors doing my courses but that would make too many letters.

Can you suggest some methods to improve this situation?

Comment: Also [Mathematics PhD after M.Sc. Physics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186692/mathematics-phd-after-m-sc-physics) and [How can I effectively switch fields from physics to math post-undergrad?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77965/how-can-i-effectively-switch-fields-from-physics-to-math-post-undergrad) and [How to become a mathematician with a physics bachelors degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/180560)

Comment: You can always submit more letters than required.